# Class Loader problem in WebSphere but does not happen in Eclipse - Okta Auth from Github

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, okta

I have the following problem:

I have created a routine in Java and imported the Okta references using Maven (https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-java) on Eclipse. I do not have a main on the code as the application will run inside a Tririga (IBM application) context. Tririga runs over WebSphere.

I exported the app as .jar file. I then upload it to Tririga Class Loader. Then I start to include the okta .jars as they are requested by the code errors, and this is the order:

okta-authn-sdk-api-1.0.0
okta-sdk-api-1.5.2
okta-commons-lang-1.1.1
okta-authn-sdk-impl-1.0.0
okta-sdk-impl-1.5.2
okta-config-check-1.1.1

On this point, it requests:

com.okta.sdk.impl.http.RequestExecutorFactory   from class: okta-sdk-httpclient; but that implementation is on this jar: okta-sdk-impl-1.5.2, which is already uploaded. I upload the class okta-sdk-impl-1.5.2 anyways but I receive the same error.

I do not have that error on Eclipse as I was able to export the .jar but why is this happening on Tririga? (running on WebSphere).

WebSphere version: 9.0.0.11 on Windows Server 2012
Tririga version: 3.6.0.4

Thank you.

Comment: Can you paste the error code details you are getting in websphere server ?

Comment: This is the error: Unable to find a 'com.okta.sdk.impl.http.RequestExecutorFactory' implementation on the classpath.  Please ensure you have added the okta-sdk-httpclient.jar file to your runtime classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following latest jar file dependency and check.

okta-sdk-api - 1.5.2
okta-sdk-impl - 1.5.2
okta-sdk-httpclient - 1.5.2

You can refer below the link and use as per maven or gradle dependency.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.okta.sdk/okta-sdk-api/1.5.2

Comment: Hi, just to discard a confusion, I am using okta-auth-java, not okta-sdk-java. 

I am using the maven references as outlined in https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-java; but I have set the latest versions (just checked and no new versions were found):

Comment: <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.okta.authn.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>okta-authn-sdk-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.okta.authn.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>okta-authn-sdk-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.okta.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>okta-sdk-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>

Comment: You can check this link, it may be helpful. https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-java/issues/49

Comment: Thank you. Please be patient with me, I am a humble sysadmin struggling with this piece of code. I have seen that link before, but that will imply to change my code. For example, on okta-auth-java, I use this method:

AuthenticationResponse AR = client.authenticate(userName, pwdInCharArray, relayState, ASH);

But now,as I have change the maven dependencies to use okta-sdk-java, I now receive 2 errors on that line:

AuthenticationResponse cannot be resolved to a type,    and 
The method authenticate(String, char[], String, TririgaAuthenticationHandler) is undefined for the type Client

Comment: on https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java suggest that for Authenticating, I should use https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-java. The one that I was initially using.

Comment: I found the error is happening on Eclipse when debugging but it does not stop the execution; what could I do to replicate this behavior on WebSphere?